Linking error with boost serialization module
I'm porting a Visual SLAM C++ project from Ubuntu to Windows. I'm able to build the package core as library and its dependency packages (g2o, DBoW2, Pangolin). However, when linking the final executable, I'm hit with the many linking errors related to boost serialization (in namespace boost::archive). I am building the debug configuration.
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) protected: __cdecl boost::archive::detail::basic_iarchive::basic_iarchive(unsigned int)" (__imp_??0basic_iarchive@detail@archive@boost@@IEAA@I@Z) referenced in function "protected: __cdecl boost::archive::detail::common_iarchive<class boost::archive::binary_iarchive>::common_iarchive<class boost::archive::binary_iarchive>(unsigned int)" (??0?$common_iarchive@Vbinary_iarchive@archive@boost@@@detail@archive@boost@@IEAA@I@Z) stereo_kitti    C:\Users\xyz\vs19\orb_slam3\build\ORB_SLAM3.lib(System.obj) 1

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __cdecl boost::archive::detail::basic_iarchive::~basic_iarchive(void)" (__imp_??1basic_iarchive@detail@archive@boost@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function "int `protected: __cdecl boost::archive::detail::common_iarchive<class boost::archive::binary_iarchive>::common_iarchive<class boost::archive::binary_iarchive>(unsigned int)'::`1'::dtor$0" (?dtor$0@?0???0?$common_iarchive@Vbinary_iarchive@archive@boost@@@detail@archive@boost@@IEAA@I@Z@4HA)  stereo_kitti    C:\Users\xyz\vs19\orb_slam3\build\ORB_SLAM3.lib(System.obj) 1

What I have tried so far:

Following advice from this answer on
SO I built Boost-1_70 from source on my windows system
I tried multiple combinations of library configurations (MDd)
(MTd) to no avail
I even tried using a different Boost version 1_77 but no help
This SO answer mentions an issue of library version mismatch. But I don't know if this is applicable (serialization is there in most versions) and also which Boost version would be suitable for me. In ubuntu I do not specify the boost version and just pass the compiler option -lboost_serialization to pick system boost libs.

At this point I've run out of idea's. Any help in resolving this error is greatly appreciated.

Additional information:

I'm using C++17 option in language standard
The project library being generated is pretty large:
ORB_SLAM3.lib   ~345 MB

The linker input (additional dependencies) are follows:
C:\dev\Boost_1_70_0\lib\libboost_system-vc142-mt-x64-1_70.lib
C:\dev\Boost_1_70_0\lib\libboost_program_options-vc142-mt-x64-1_70.lib
C:\dev\Boost_1_70_0\lib\libboost_serialization-vc142-mt-x64-1_70.lib
C:\dev\Boost_1_70_0\lib\libboost_iostreams-vc142-mt-x64-1_70.lib
C:\dev\Boost_1_70_0\lib\libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-x64-1_70.lib
C:\dev\Boost_1_70_0\lib\libboost_container-vc142-mt-x64-1_70.lib
C:\dev\Boost_1_70_0\lib\libboost_thread-vc142-mt-x64-1_70.lib
Release\ORB_SLAM3.lib
C:\dev\Boost_1_70_0\lib\libboost_chrono-vc142-mt-x64-1_70.lib
C:\dev\opencv\build\x64\vc15\lib\opencv_world3413.lib
..\Thirdparty\Pangolin\build\Release\pango_glgeometry.lib
..\Thirdparty\Pangolin\build\Release\pango_geometry.lib
..\Thirdparty\Pangolin\build\Release\pango_python.lib
..\Thirdparty\Pangolin\build\Release\pango_plot.lib
..\Thirdparty\Pangolin\build\Release\pango_scene.lib
..\Thirdparty\Pangolin\build\Release\pango_tools.lib
..\Thirdparty\Pangolin\build\Release\pango_display.lib
..\Thirdparty\Pangolin\build\Release\pango_vars.lib
..\Thirdparty\Pangolin\build\Release\pango_video.lib
..\Thirdparty\Pangolin\build\Release\pango_packetstream.lib
..\Thirdparty\Pangolin\build\Release\pango_windowing.lib
..\Thirdparty\Pangolin\build\Release\pango_opengl.lib
..\Thirdparty\Pangolin\build\Release\pango_image.lib
..\Thirdparty\Pangolin\build\Release\pango_core.lib
C:\dev\vcpkg\packages\glew_x64-windows\lib\glew32.lib
opengl32.lib
glu32.lib
..\Thirdparty\Pangolin\build\Release\tinyobj.lib
..\Thirdparty\DBoW2\lib\Debug\DBoW2.lib
Thirdparty\g2o\Debug\g2o.lib
kernel32.lib
user32.lib
gdi32.lib
winspool.lib
shell32.lib
ole32.lib
oleaut32.lib
uuid.lib
comdlg32.lib
advapi32.lib
  
  

Next thing I'm going to try is to use an older version of Boost.

So you forgot to link something. Perhaps this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

@JesperJuhl I doubt if that's the case here. As I mentioned before, I compile the project in ubuntu with boost serialization library.  The features for whom the symbol issues are being reported are also related to archiving (part of serialization). Take a look at this answer

Check that boost stage dir is in your AdditionalLibraryDirectories. Boost uses autolinking on Windows.

@Osyotr Sorry for naive question: What's a stage dir? Is that the lib directory containing the lib files?

Yes https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_85_0/more/getting_started/windows.html

@Osyotr  The stage dir is included in the AdditionalLibraryDirectories. No changes, still same linking errors.
